# Yii access control for a visitor guest user

Tags: php, yii, access-control

I need a access control in yii  for two users . 
1. authenticated user : all access
2) logged out user : if a user is logout and view some contact system will automatically login with a guest user.

Now what i want that the guest user will have a limited access. although user is logged in and is an authenticated user .

what i have tried is

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions' => array('viewgoal','getdescription'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),

            array('deny',  // deny all guest user
                    'actions'=>array('Maingoal','delete','create'),
                    'users'=>array('guest'),
                ),
                array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

it restrict the user to access the page . But i want user can see the form to create but restrict to submit . I need a common solution as i have near about 100 forms on many pages . Please help

Comment: use roles or put ifs arround your code that only the logedin users can see: if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use access rules to restrict only part of your code.

But you can do that using [roles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth) inside your code.

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isAdmin) {
    echo CHtml::submitButton();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Authenticated users:

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
   echo "Authenticated";
}
```

For Guest users:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
   echo "Guest";
}
```

Comment: i know this dude . check my ans for me guest is also a logged in user .